# How can I insert a list to MySQL through Python?

Tags: python, mysql, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get sensor data from Arduino to RPi through USB, read it in Python and insert it to a MySQL database. Even though the data type that I am trying to insert is clearly a string I get the following error:

"TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple"

The database that I am trying to implement has generally a 6 float and at the end 1 int type values but according to the other sources they say that whatever type should be, the data should be sent as string. So what can I do to solve this problem?

**My database:**

```
 +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| humidity   | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| temperatur | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lightlevel | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| airquality | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lpg        | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gas        | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pir        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Here is my code:**

```
import serial
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user="root", passwd = "password", db = "sensordata")
cur = db.cursor()

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)


while 1:
        serread = ser.readline()
        a_list = serread.split()
        map_object = map(float, a_list)
        list_of_integers = list(map_object)
        sql = ("""INSERT INTO datas VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (str(list_of_integers[0]), str(list_of_integers[1]), str(list_of_integers[2]), str(list_of_integers[3]), str(list_of_integers[4]), str(list_of_integers[5]), str(list_of_integers[6])))
        cur.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        print(list_of_integers)
#       print(type(str(list_of_integers[0])))
```

Thank you.

Comment: you're passing a single `tuple` to `execute()` instead two parameters. Should be either `execute(*sql)` or `execute(sql[0], sql[1])`

Comment: Yup. Execute(*sql) solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because in the following line you have written the mysql command in form of a comment rather than a string:

```
sql = ("""INSERT INTO datas VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (str(list_of_integers[0]), str(list_of_integers[1]), str(list_of_integers[2]), str(list_of_integers[3]), str(list_of_integers[4]), str(list_of_integers[5]), str(list_of_integers[6])))
```

Try using this line instead:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO datas VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (str(list_of_integers[0]), str(list_of_integers[1]), str(list_of_integers[2]), str(list_of_integers[3]), str(list_of_integers[4]), str(list_of_integers[5]), str(list_of_integers[6])))
```